# Javascript bundler building stuck at 99%

Tags: react-native, expo

Expo react-native app does not load on connected iphone

When I start my app using the command below:

```
expo start --tunnel
```

I get the following error:

```
Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
Unable to resolve "react-native-vector-icons/AntDesign" from 
"node_modules/react-native-elements/src/helpers/getIconType.js"
Building JavaScript bundle [=================================================================================================== ] 99%
```

I am using ios 10.13.6 High Sierra.

Anybody have seen this issue before? any suggestions to debug or resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are not using the babel preset which is set up when you initialize a project in expo. this preset remaps `react-native-vector-icons` to `@expo/vector-icons`, so you would not see this error if you were using it.

**if you are using sdk32**, you can fix that by creating `babel.config.js` in your project (and removing `.babelrc` if there is one) and adding this to `babel.config.js`:

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
  };
};
```

now close the packager and run `expo start -c`.

**if you are using an older sdk version than sdk32**, you can just edit `.babelrc` (or create it if it doesn't exist) and change it to this:

```
{
  "presets": ["babel-preset-expo"],
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "plugins": ["transform-react-jsx-source"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed react-native-elements from package.json. I then ran the following command:

rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json; npm install

then issued the following command:

expo start -c --tunnel

This seemed to have fixed the issue. I need the native-react-elements package so the next thing is that I am going to add it back and try to test with different versions of react-native-elements package.

Comment: It looks like `react-native-elements` has a peer dependency of `react-native-vector-icons`, so you will have to install that as well.

Comment: @zaytrix, Should not npm install all dependencies for a package? The solution suggested above by brentvante seems to have fixed the issue.

Comment: Peer dependencies have to be installed on their own. However, if you are using Expo, it does have its own version of react-native-vector-icons pre-installed, which is why brentvante's solution works.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks @zaytix!